# Batch file to ping and display different output

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

I'm trying to create a batch file to ping a few devices to output a .txt that shows the results.

```
ping -n 1 router | find "TTL" > nul

IF errorlevel 1 (
echo "Cannot ping" > DIRECTORY
)
ELSE (
echo "Ping success" > DIRECTORY
)
```

Currently I can only show whether it succeeds or fails. However I'm thinking if there is a way to differentiate between **how** it fails e.g. request time out VS host unreachable.

Does anyone know how I can tweak it?

EDIT:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('ping -n 2 router ^| findstr "Reply timed Hardware"') do set "res=%%~i"
if not "%res:timed=%" == "%res%" echo "Time out" > C:\Users\eddie\Desktop\results\timeout.txt
if not "%res:unreachable=unreachable%" == "%res%" echo "Destination host is unreachable" > C:\Users\eddie\Desktop\results\unreach.txt 
if not "%res:Reply=%" == "%res%" echo "successful ping" > C:\Users\eddie\Desktop\results\success.txt

pause
```

Comment: I will create an example answer, but you're welcome to start [`reading here`](https://www.linksys.com/fi/support-article?articleNum=135197)

Comment: Type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and check your `if`/`else` syntax…

Answer (score 1):

Here is an untested example, I cannot test this now because I am not able to setup any routing that will create various results such as `Destination host unreachable` which comes from the router:

```
@echo off
set "host=router"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('ping -n 2 %host% ^| findstr "TTL timed request unreachable"') do set "res=%%~i"
if not "%res:timed=%" == "%res%" (echo Time out)>"%userprofile%\Desktop\timeout.txt"
if not "%res:request=%" == "%res%" (echo Unknown Host)>"%userprofile%\Desktop\unknownhost.txt"
if not "%res:unreachable=unreachable%" == "%res%" (echo Destination host is unreachable)>"%userprofile%\Desktop\unreach.txt"
if not "%res:TTL=%" == "%res%" (echo Successful ping)>"%userprofile%\Desktop\success.txt"
```

The concept is simply, the `findstr` will capture only results from any of `Reply` or `timed` or `hardware`. We then just test if the string contains a substring and echo accordingly.

The second option in the list to capture `unreachable` has the `& goto :EOF` option simply because it will contain either just `destination host unreachable` or `Reply from ... : Destination host unreachable` like the below screenshot. We do not want to create both messages for `Unreachable` and Reply (which comes from the Router).

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I'm trying to understand your code piece by piece... so please correct me. So for the first line.... the PING function will be performed and each line of the output of the PING tossed into the "i" variable and processed. That part I think I got it, however what does the FINDSTR "REPLY TIMED HARDWARE" do? Also, the SET "RES=%%~i"? Does this set the string into RES variable? Also, what does the %RES:TIMED=%" do?

Comment: It is simple. I am testing the results of ping to find if the string contains specific words, if it does I customize the output result. if you want to see how it works, put an `echo` before each `if` statement and see how substring substitution makes this work.

Comment: Oh shoot, thanks for the super fast response! I was just editing my comment. Okay will do so and get back..!

Comment: Hi Gerhard, the script doesn't seem to work. I've been trying to edit a little on my side for the past two days now but nothing seems to change. Regardless of what the ping response is (I've tried pinging an available IP vs one that's not available), but both are returning successful pings. (I added an output .txt file to show the echo).

Comment: Can you edit the question with the edited code you are running?

Comment: Just did! Running it gave me a "success.txt" at all time, even when I pinged an invalid IP address instead of a "unreach.txt"

Comment: Ok  will look at it now. What is the response from that IP you are pinging which is invalid? Or what is the IP you are pinging?

Comment: I have edited my answer with what you want. Copy the code as is, do not edit anything other than host to ping.